# Selenium WebDriver tests failure in TFS build process

Tags: c#, selenium, tfs, build-process

I use ChromeDriver for web application testing. Unit tests work OK locally on my machine. But when I start automated test run on build server it fails with an exception on `new ChromeDriver()`:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified.

All required binaries exist in `TestResults\Out` folder. Sample console program with ChromeDriver works fine on build machine. I tried to start build service in interactive (console) mode, but it did not help either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably a silly question, but is Chrome installed on the build server at the location specified here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Comment: @James, sure. I ran console test program on the build machine and it worked fine. I also checked the location manually.

Comment: Where is Chrome located?

Comment: @Arran, C:\Users\dfedorkov\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe. I ran the service as user dfedorkov.

Comment: @DmitryFedorkov, have you tried installing Chrome to a more central location, i.e in the root of C:\ for instance, and then point Selenium to that? It's a hassle though.

Comment: @Arran, the test must also run locally on any developer's machine, so I cannot change Chrome folder arbitrary. I tried now to log in build server as user buildserver (that is normally used for builds), install Chrome for this user, then run build service in interactive (console) mode and run gated check-in on it. But the same error occured.